# How to get control of outlook email body of newly creating mail dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am creating addin. I want to get control of email body in C# so  what i write on body part can be send through server side.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly i want :

Outlook.Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

Outlook.Inspector inspector = application.ActiveInspector();

Outlook.MailItem myMailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)inspector.CurrentItem;

string subjectEmail = myMailItem.Subject;

string bodyEmail = myMailItem.Body;

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to get access of Email body part and format it on wish. That you can do it using below code.

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

mail.Body = "Put your simple custom message here";

//mail.IsBodyHtml = true; //If you want html specific formatting in your code.

Example

mail.Body = "This email sent by the xyz
**this is bold text!**"

mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

Comment: I do not want to add custom message. I only want to get control to modify the message written in body part through c#